# Number of Perfect Matching in Complete Graph - Proof Explanation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Want to find the number of perfect matching in a complete graph K2n where 2n is the number of vertices:

Came up with the following method -

1. Counting Edges

```
>Total no. of edges = C(2n,2), Choose 1 edge in C(2n,2) ways.
>Remaining no. of edges C(2n-2,2). (Since 2 vertices already selected.
>So, no. of ways of choosing 2 edges = C(2n,2)*C(2n-2,2).
>Total ways of choosing edges -> C(2n,2)*C(2n-2,2)*..*C(2,2)
> => ((2n)!)/(2^n) *(Note: Missing n! in denominator)*
```

Referred - [How to find the number of perfect matchings in complete graphs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60894/how-to-find-the-number-of-perfect-matchings-in-complete-graphs). My understanding(and doubts) for this method is given below:

2. Counting with Vertices

```
>Choose a vertex. Choose another vertex (part of same edge): 2n-1 ways.*(Why no. of ways of selecting first vertex not considered??)*
>Choose next vertex. Choose the pair vertex (part of same edge): 2n-3 ways.
>So end result - (2n-1)*(2n-3)*..*(3)*(1) (Product of all odd numbers less than 2n)
>Simplification gives -> ((2n)!)/((2^n)*n!)
```

The 1st and 2nd method essentially becomes the same if in the 2nd method I consider no. of ways of choosing the first vertex in a pair and also divides each pair selection by 2! (since order of choosing vertices in each pair doesn't matter)

1.What am I missing in the 1st method?
2.Why number of ways of choosing the starting vertex not considered when selecting each pair of vertices in 2nd method?

Comment: Your issue is ordering. In your first count, you impose an order on the edges in the matching, by picking one edge first, the next second, etc. Effectively, you end up counting each matching $n!$ times. This is also why the second count does not "select" the first vertex in each pair...to avoid this ordering issue.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thanks for explaining!