# Is there any formula for counting the number of 1-factorizations of a complete graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

For a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) $K_{2n}$, one can easily get the number of perfect matchings (i.e. 1-factors) with the formula ${(2n)!}/({n!*2^n})$ (see the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60894/how-to-find-the-number-of-perfect-matchings-in-complete-graphs) and OEIS [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147)). In [graph factorizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization), 1-factorizations of a complete garph $K_{2n}$ are the partitions of the edges into 1-factors.

The OEIS sequence [A000438](https://oeis.org/A000438) describes the number of 1-factorizations of $K_{2n}$. It seems that counting the number of 1-factorizations of $K_{2n}$ is very difficult.

I wonder is there any formula for calculating number of 1-factorizations?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2511611/383078) tell you what you want to know?

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank you! that’s a good reference and looks very interesting. However I think it’s a bit different from the number of 1-factorizations of a complete graph.

Comment: No, it is the same thing. If you take a $(2n-1)$-coloring of $K_{2n}$, then every color class is a $1$-factor, so what you get is exactly a $1$-factorization. (The other question is a bit more general, because it also looks at $(2n-1)$-colorings of $K_{2n-1}$.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov,  thank you for pointing this. The reason that I think they were different is because I took $Sn$ as the formula, which didn't give the sequence 1,6,6240 for $Sn$ (n=4,6,8).

Comment: @MishaLavrov, yes, I agree that every color class is a 1-factor (i.e perfect matching) but I still think it doesn't directly give the number of 1-factorization.